# Where to place entities that are global to an app?

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a large Symfony2 app that has the following bundles (all under the same vendor name): Login, Register, Blog, Forum. The official docs say that forum related entities belong in the Forum bundle, and Blog related entities belong in the Blog bundle. But what about my User and Account entities? Both are created during the registration process, and User is used during the login process. I consider those entities to be global to the app b/c their use isn't limited to one feature (again, per Symfony docs, one 'feature' per bundle.) I'm wondering what the best practice for this would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `UsersBundle` and in future store other code, related to users in this bundle.